# python logging with multiple modules does not work

Tags: python, logging

I created some Python files keeping my functions a bit separated to ease working / fixing. All files are in one directory. The structure may get broken down to something like:

- a.py (a class A with basic stuff)
- b.py (a class B with basic stuff)
- modA.py (create a class C deriving from A and B)
- modB.py (create a class D deriving from A and B)
- ...
- main_a.py (using class C)
- main_b.py (using class D)

Every module uses the logging stuff from python. An why so ever - only the root logger messages are written. And I don't see my error.

Here is a minimal example.

`a.py`

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        logger.debug("Instance of A")
```

`b.py`

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        logger.debug("Instance of B")
```

`ab.py`

```
import a
import b
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class AB(a.A, b.B):
    def __init__(self):
        logger.debug("Instance of AB")
        a.A.__init__(self)
        b.B.__init__(self)
```

`main_one.py`

```
import sys
import ab

import logging
import logging.handlers
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stderr)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.warning("The trouble starts")

ab = ab.AB()
```

I also tried to use something like `self.logger = logging.getLogger(type(self).__name__)` to do logging on a per class base, but the result is the same. So may one of you point out where I went wrong when reading the python logging manuals?

TIA.

**EDIT 1: My solution**

Thanks to both, @falsetru and @Jakub M., using both answers leads to a working solution.

First I put everything in a hierarchy.

```
main_one.py
  lib/
    __init__.py
    ab.py
    basic/
      __init__.py
      a.py
      b.py
```

Second I changed the `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` in `main_one.py` to `logger = logging.getLogger()` (*No name for the root logger!*).

That did the trick.

Very helpful was a code snippet [on GitHub](https://github.com/mapio/sdt/tree/master/1_observing/active/logging).

Answer (score 2):

Do `print __name__` for each of your modules and see what you get there actually. You should put your modules into proper directories so `__name__` is a ["period separated hierarchical value"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects). For example, if your file hierarchy looked like:

```
main_a.py
libs/
  __init__.py
  a.py
  modA.py
```

then `__name__` of your modules (`a.py` and `modA.py`) would be `libs.a` and `libs.modA`

> The name is potentially a period-separated hierarchical value, like
>   foo.bar.baz (though it could also be just plain foo, for example).
>   Loggers that are further down in the hierarchical list are children of
>   loggers higher up in the list. For example, given a logger with a name
>   of foo, loggers with names of foo.bar, foo.bar.baz, and foo.bam are
>   all descendants of foo. The logger name hierarchy is analogous to the
>   Python package hierarchy, and identical to it if you organise your
>   loggers on a per-module basis using the recommended construction
>   logging.getLogger(**name**). That’s because in a module, **name** is
>   the module’s name in the Python package namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Use same logger name for all module. `__name__` is module name; `a`, `b`, `ab`, `main_one` ...

```
logger = logging.getLogger('daniel_lib')
```

Comment: Ok - that solves the problem on a working base, but still brings some questions. As far as I can see, I'm loosing portability?

Comment: @daniel I don't understand what you mean by `loosing portability`.

Comment: Well - I may use a fixed logger name in all modules, but than I have to use this logger name _always_ if I work with these modules? [This one](https://github.com/mapio/sdt/tree/master/1_observing/active/logging) seems to do the trick using a dir structure and a config.